# Order when iterating over an dictionary

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary

When iterating over a dictionary in C#, are we guaranteed that the order will be same every time we iterate this dictionary?

```
  foreach (var key in myDict.Keys)
  {
    ...               
  }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384710/why-is-a-dictionary-not-ordered and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007782/the-order-of-elements-in-dictionary

Comment: By the way, if you need an ordered dictionary use an [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx). It has the same lookup performance but is slower on inserting/deleting and needs extra memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx), no, there is no guarantee:

> The order of the keys in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` is *unspecified*,but it is the same order as the associated values in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` returned by the Values property.